# Express + PassportJS no recibe mensajes flash

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, passport

Estoy trabjando en un proyecto que utiliza un servidor Express 4 y PassportJS para autenticar usuarios del lado del servidor. El problema es que la estrategia local no envía mensajes flash a la ruta de redirección como indica la [documentación](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/).

1. Instalé [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) con NPM.
2. Agregué el método `flash()` como Middleware a Express:

```js
import * as express from 'express';
import * as flash from 'connect-flash';

const app = express();
...
app.use(flash());
```

3. Agregué un tercer parámetro al método `done()` en el código de la estrategia para autenticar usuarios:

```js
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';

export default new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, async (email, password, done) => {
    const ref = db.collection('usuarios').doc(email);
    const doc = await ref.get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
        return done(null, false, { error: 'Usuario inexistente' });
    }
    ...
});
```

4. Agregué opciones para redirigir con mensajes flash al obtener un error en la ruta de autenticación:

```js
router.post(
    '/ingreso',
    (req: Request, res: Response, next) => { /* pre-autenticación */ },
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/api/v1/administracion/autenticacion/ingreso',
        failureFlash: true
    }),
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => { /* post-autenticación */ }
);
```

5. Leo el mensaje flash con el método `req.flash()` en la ruta de redirección `/api/v1/administracion/autenticacion/ingreso`:

```js
router.get('/ingreso', (req: any, res: Response) => {
    const resultado: IResultado = {
        message: '',
        data: null,
        ok: false
    };
    if (req.flash('error')) {
        resultado.message = req.flash('error');
        console.log(req.flash('error'));
    }
    return res.status(400).json(resultado);
});
```

Sin embargo, el método `req.flash('error')` devuelve un array vacío. ¿Alguna idea de porqué esto no funciona?